# Create and pass IEnumerable to method in one line

Tags: c#, ienumerable

i have this few lines of code

```
FilterCondition CustomerID = new FilterCondition("Customer_ID",cust.Customer_ID,FilterCondition.FilterOperator.Equals);
        List<FilterCondition> conditions = new List<FilterCondition>();
        conditions.Add(CustomerID);
        conditions.Add(Location_is_last_used);
        Location loct = Store.Select<Location>(conditions).First();
```

I tried to make it work like this

```
Store.Count<Customer>(new List<FilterCondition>().Add(new FilterCondition("Customer_name",name,FilterCondition.FilterOperator.Equals))
```

But this wont work because Add returns void and its running me crazy, is there any other way to solve this in one line? i realy dont want to write conditions for everything that i need.

Tnx for help!
Regards,
Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static ICollection<T> AddChainable<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T newItem)
    {
        collection.Add(newItem);
        return collection;
    }
}
```

You could then invoke this as follows:

```
Store.Count<Customer>(new List<FilterCondition>().AddChainable(new FilterCondition("Customer_name",name,FilterCondition.FilterOperator.Equals));
```

(assuming `Store.Count<T>` works on `ICollection<T>`, which introduces the `Count` property, otherwise adapt the collection type appropriately.

The advantage over the list initializer syntax is that you could use this also for already created list objects (e.g. if you get the list object from a factory method).

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for, comming from years of C i forgot about extention methods. You realy made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Store.Count<Customer>(new FilterCondition[]{new FilterCondition("Customer_name",name,FilterCondition.FilterOperator.Equals)}.ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
new List<FilterConditions>() { new FilterCondition("Customer_name",name,FilterCondition.FilterOperator.Equals) }
```

as List initializer

Answer (score 0):

First of wall, I wouldn't do that, cause the code already good one, but if you **really** want to do that, one of possible **pseudocode**  could be:

```
Location loct = Store.Select<Location>(new List<FilterCondition>{
           new FilterCondition{value = CustomerID}, 
            new FilterCondition{value = Location_is_last_used}
}).First();
```

*Should* work for you.

Repeat, in my opinion, your code is a *way* better. It's easier to read.

Comment: What crazy syntax is this ...?

Comment: @dbaseman: Corrected, I ammited the properties before. Code is just a concept.